# AWS Cloudformation IF-ELSE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to have an IF-ELSE statement to assign subnets.

If 1 AZ is being used, assign privatesubnet1 to subnets

If 2 AZ is being used, assign privatesubnet1 and privatesubnet2 to subnets

If 3 AZ is being used, assign privatesubnet1, privatesubnet2 and privatesubnet3 to subnets

The IF function handles 1 and 2 AZ well, but I don’t know how to handle 3 AZ

Suggestions are welcome.

```
Conditions:
  SingleZone:
    !Equals [!Ref NumberOfZones, 1]
  TwoZones:
    !Equals [!Ref NumberOfZones, 2]
  ThreeZones:
    !Equals [!Ref NumberOfZones, 3]
Resources:
  Properties:
    Subnets:
      - !If [TwoZones, !Join [',', [!Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2]], !Ref PrivateSubnet1]
      #- !If [ThreeZones, !Join [',', [!Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2, !Ref PrivateSubnet3]],????]
```

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mapping to avoid IF-ELSE

```
--
Parameters:
  NumberOfZones:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - AZ1
      - AZ2
      - AZ3

Mappings:
  PrivateSubnet:
      AZ1: 
            Subnets: <insert your subnets>
      AZ2: 
            Subnets: <insert your subnets>
      AZ3: 
            Subnets: <insert your subnets>
```